# pyspark ignore lineSep option

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We have a csv file that has a `\n` character inside one column:

[image]

My settings are

```
        'inferSchema': False,  # Read in columns as StringType
        'header': True,
        'sep': ',',
        'quote': '"',
        'escape': '"',
        'lineSep': '\r',
        'multiLine': column_language == 'en',
        'unescapedQuoteHandling': 'RAISE_ERROR',
        'mode': 'FAILFAST',
        'enforceSchema': False,
    }
```

Note specifically `lineSep` set to a carriage return and not a newline.

`spark.read.csv(path=f, **csv_params)`
But spark (3.2.0) does not care. It still splits the row incorrectly.

Comment: what is that `'multiLine': column_language == 'en',`?

Answer (score 0):

Writing this csv file:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
1,2,3
1,"text
",4
1,2,3
```

And using your options, everything works as it should, **if you NOT USE as lineSep = \r**. I'm sure the problem is in that point. Your lines seem to be splitted by "\n", just remove the "lineSep" from your options.